Почему printf ("%f", n1) выводит 3.000000, вместо 43.000000? Вводим 32
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float r;
    scanf("%f",&r);
     float n1 = printf("%.0f\n",trunc ( r*pow(1024,2)*pow(760*1024,-1) ));   
printf ("%f", n1);

    return 0;
}


float r;
scanf("%f",&r);

Ввели 32
float n1 = printf("%.0f\n",trunc ( r*pow(1024,2)*pow(760*1024,-1) ));

Вычислили и вывели 43 без десятичных цифр (запрошено "%.0f\n")
В n1 (которое зачем-то float) вывели количество выведенных символов - их 3 (включая символ новой строки).
printf ("%f", n1);

Вывели эту тройку. По умолчанию - с шестью цифрами после точки ("%f").
Что не так?
